# Is it possible to add a decorator to a class after its creation in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs, typescript-decorator

I would like to update a class with inversify's @injectable decorator after its creation; the use case is I want to use a mocking lib like ts-auto-mock to create a mock for me, and then apply the @injectable decorator after, so I can bind the mock to the service type.

```
const mockExampleService = createMock<ExampleService>();
// I want to apply the @injectable decorator to mockExampleService here

// inversify.unit-config.ts
const container = new Container();
const.bind<ExampleService>(TYPES.ExampleService).to(mockExampleService);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure! Inversify provides a [decorate](https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/068732327fcbfe061975d1400e582120fea4ea36/src/annotation/decorator_utils.ts#L66) function for exactly that purpose.

```js
const mockExampleService = createMock<ExampleService>();
decorate(injectable(), mockExampleService);

// inversify.unit-config.ts
const container = new Container();
const.bind<ExampleService>(TYPES.ExampleService).to(mockExampleService);
```